# I receive null when I access to another fragment from onDismiss - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I want to refresh the main fragment. So I am using an onDismiss method in DialogFragment to use inside there the method refreshFragment to refresh the mainfragment. I don't know If this is the best option... But I receive a null object.

This is mi method onDismiss:

```
 @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface frag) {
        super.onDismiss(frag);
        this.getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyTeamFragment fragm = (MyTeamFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my_team_id); //HERE IS NULL
        fragm.refreshFragmnet();

    }
```

And this is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.karate_manager.Fragments.MyTeamFragment.refreshFragmnet()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.karate_manager.DialogFragment.AcceptBidRivalDialogFragment.onDismiss(AcceptBidRivalDialogFragment.java:153)
```

Comment: You cannot refresh `FragmentA` in `FragmentB`'s `onDismiss()` method. You need a better strategy to tackle this, like e.g. doing so from the hosting Activity (which is also a somewhat bad idea in itself)

Comment: An what is the best idea??

Comment: A better idea would be to have your `FragmentB` convert the received `context` in it's `onAttach()` method, and try casting it to `FragmentUpdaterInterface`. Then, in `FragmentB::onDismiss()` i calls `fragmentUpdater.update()` and the activity hosting this fragment has to implement the `FragmentUpdaterInterface`

Comment: This idea, however, is also not that great - because then your FragmentB cannot be used anywhere, but only from activities that implement the required interface. So, you have a couple of options: 1) pick up a better design for organizing code. MVVM / CLEAN are both decent examples of this. 2) make the `FragmentB` fire a broadcast using the `LocalBroadcastManager` and make fragments that need to be updated from elsewhere listen to that broadcast. (this way the fragment can be used from any activity) 3) go with a simple interface and make the host activity call `fragInstance.update()`

Comment: my first comment is pretty much a suggestion to use 3). The "best idea" depends on other factors which are unknown from your question, so more information and detail would be necessary to suggest one. However, that would be better off as a new, different question. The "best" and most maintanable version is 1), because you don't need to tell your fragment to update, the reactive nature of MVVM/CLEAN will automatically do that for you by publishing new data. From some `Repository`. Using a LiveData / RxJava stream.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using MVVM is too difficult for me, I am just a rookie... haha I will try to do it in another way because also I have the connection between this fragment in the adapter with a button...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should introduction your fragment class to xml code

```
android:name="your fragment class"
```